# getting the value of selected options using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.sysem").click(function(){
        var selectedvalue = $(".sysem option:selected").val();
        var hidden = document.getElementById('prens');
        hidden.value += selectedvalue;

    });
});
```

and this is my html code

```
<form method='post'>
<select id='psy' class='sysem' name='psy' multiple='true' size='5'>
<option value='s1'>Sample1</option>
<option value='s2'>Sample2</option>
<option value='s3'>Sample3</option>
</select>
<textarea id='prens' name='prens' coloumn='20' row='5'></textarea>
</form>
```

now my problem is when i select Sample1 then i hold the `Ctrl button` so that i can select another option, and then i select Sample2 the result in the textarea is `s1s1s1` it should be `s1s2s3`. But When i start selecting at the bottom the result is ok `s3s2s1`.

It seem's that when i start selecting at the top to bottom the result becomes redundunt and if i start selecting at the bottom to top the result is ok...

can anybody help me... im a newbie in programming..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is `select` instead of `option`, that's why you get always the first`:selected` value.

Try this instead

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select.sysem option").click(function(){
    var hidden = document.getElementById('prens');
    hidden.value += this.value;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method='post'>
  <select id='psy' class='sysem' name='psy' multiple='true' size='5'>
    <option value='s1'>Sample1</option>
    <option value='s2'>Sample2</option>
    <option value='s3'>Sample3</option>
  </select>
  <textarea id='prens' name='prens' coloumn='20' row='5'></textarea>
</form>
```

If you want to only get the selected ones:

```js
jQuery(function($){ // DOM ready

  $("select.sysem").on("change", function(){
    var sel = $(":selected", this).map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join();
    $('#prens').val(sel);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method='post'>
  <select id='psy' class='sysem' name='psy' multiple='true' size='5'>
    <option value='s1'>Sample1</option>
    <option value='s2'>Sample2</option>
    <option value='s3'>Sample3</option>
  </select>
  <textarea id='prens' name='prens' coloumn='20' row='5'></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Master.. :D

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` and similar methods that are supposed to return something about an element, like value or attribute value, will only return the data from the first element that is matched.

So when you do

```
$(".sysem option:selected").val();
```

And select the options top down `s1` is always going to be the first one encountered, and why you got `s1s1s1`

If you want all the values of a multiple select element just call `.val()` on the select element itself. It will return an array of all selected values

```
var values = $(".sysem").val();
jQuery('#prens').val( values.join(",") );
```

Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.sysem").change(function(){
        var values = $(".sysem").val();
        $('#prens').val(values.join(","));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method='post'>
<select id='psy' class='sysem' name='psy' multiple='true' size='5'>
<option value='s1'>Sample1</option>
<option value='s2'>Sample2</option>
<option value='s3'>Sample3</option>
</select>
<textarea id='prens' name='prens' coloumn='20' row='5'></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: While you are explaining why it happens, you haven't given a solution to the OP's problem. As clicking from top-bottom should not give `s1,s2,s3`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, Why shouldn't it give that?

Comment: *"But When i start selecting at the bottom the result is ok `s3s2s1`."*, to be fair it's not entirely clear how the OP wants the textbox to work.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, OP said it was ok, not that it was supposed to be in order of being clicked. The title of the question is _"getting the value of selected options"_ which is what is being done, nothing in the post itself states any requirements of format

Comment: Where did they say that? To me it seems they very much want it in the order they where clicked

Answer (score 0):

This will alert each selected values

```js
$(function () {
    var arr = [];
    $('#show').click(function () {
        $('#multipleSelect :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
            arr[i] = $(selected).text();
            alert(arr[i]);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<select id="multipleSelect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="show" value="Show values" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, redone, in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aau6aaL1/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.sysem").click(function(){
        $('select.sysem :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
            var hidden = document.getElementById('prens');
            console.log($(selected).text());
            hidden.value += $(selected).text();
        });
    });
});
```

Explanation: You needed to iterate through each selected value using the `.each()`. Before it was grabbing the first selected value. That is why when you went top to bottom it always said "s1" because "s1" was always the first. Opposite, when you went bottom to top the first selected changed. "s3" -> "s2" -> "s1".

Comment: Thanks @theblindprophet

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$(".sysem option:selected")` you are getting the value of the *first* selected element in a mulit-selection on the `<select>` element. In order to get the value of the element you only need to do `$(".sysem").val()`, this will return an array of the selected elements in a top-down fashion.

Although the problem is with multiple selection it's not obvious which item you want. Since it seems you are just wanting the most recently clicked item; you may want to have you click event on the option elements and get their value instead:

```
$("select.sysem option").click(function(){
    var selectedvalue = $(this).val();
    var hidden = document.getElementById('prens');
    hidden.value += selectedvalue;
});
```